# Docker File and Docker-Compose Prisma and mysql with ExpressJs Rest-api dockerization not worked

Tags: docker, express, rest, docker-compose, prisma

I was created expressjs based rest-api root file src/ inside all the api ts file are there. I trying to dockerize the all setup like mysql and prisma and express app. but not working i'm getting error I will share my dockerfile and compose file

**error on prisma client connection**

```
   {
      "error": {
        "name": "PrismaClientInitializationError",
        "clientVersion": "5.9.1"
      }
    }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --lower_case_table_names=1
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: mysql
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - DATABASE_URL:${DATABASE_URL}
    ports:
      - '3307:3307'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./prisma/migrations/20240131085242_init/migration.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migration.sql

  server:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb 
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: server
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    links:
      - mysqldb

volumes: 
  db:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY prisma ./prisma
RUN npx prisma generate
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD npm run dev
```

**prisma-schema**

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum Status {
  active
  inactive
}

model Users {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  email String @unique
  password String
  status Status? @default(active)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://dbuser:dbpassword@mysqldb:3307/docker_db"
```